# linux scheduler

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

In my kernel configuration CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set. Since schedule() is not allowed in interrupt handler how does round robin type of scheduling is implemented in linux kernel. i.e. Who calls the scheduler so often. In entry_32.S it calls preempt_schedule_irq only if CONFIG_PREEMPT is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is the timer on the CPU is set to interrupt the kernel every so often. But we can't just call schedule from interrupt context right? So what the kernel does is a neat trick. It changes the currently executing task while executing the handler and then returns. What this effectively does is switch out the context from underneath the handler so the handler completes but at the same time the next context to run is now the next task that will execute. Read up on `do_context_switch` (IIRC I think that's what it's called) and you will see that it switches it's stack and context from underneath the current execution and resumes the same function in another context.

And `CONFIG_PREEMPT` only applies to kernel code preemption in kernel context. Userspace tasks will always preempt. All this means is that any kernel code that starts to execute runs to completion (unless you call schedule() yourself or block waiting for I/O, etc....). Normally the kernel can preempt as long as it does not hold any locks except in certain cases where acquiring a lock can put the thread to sleep.

Comment: I think the handler can't just change the current executing task. what happens if the current process is holding a spin_lock and an timer interrupt comes?

Comment: @user1428099 The timer interrupt is ignored if the current kernel context has a reference count (is holding a spinlock), there's a check for it in the schedule() function that checks if it should switch the context or not. So the interrupt handler runs, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user1428099 This does not apply to userspace tasks holding locks though, they manage their own wakeup and sleep procedures but cannot be non-preemptible as this could cause a deadlock on a core, in the kernel this is acceptable as any condition that would deadlock a core would bring down the system eventually or leave you with a spinning core.